# Enviar form con onClick. Solo Javascript y HTML

Tags: javascript, html

estoy haciendo la parte de carrito de compras de una pagina (Es un trabajo de la universidad, recien estoy empezando). Por cada articulo en el carrito se deberia poder aumentar y disminuir la cantidad comprada. Logre hacerlo pero solo con un producto, si copio y pego varias veces deja de funcionar por completo. Creo yo que es porque al tener todos el mismo nombre no sabe a cual incrementar o disminuir y por eso no funciona. Tengo este codigo:

```
<div class="cantidadProducto">
     <p>Cantidad</p>
     <form name="formCantidad">
           <a onclick="aumentarUno(formCantidad)"><i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i></a>
           <input type="text" name="numero" class="numeroCantidadProducto" value="1" ReadOnly>
           <a onclick="disminuirUno(formCantidad)"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></a>
     </form>
</div>
```

Quiero enviar el formulario con el name="formCantidad", pero como eso se va a repetir en cada producto comprado solo quiero enviar el de ese articulo. Como podria hacer? Intente usar el this.formCantidad pero no funciona. Por si sirve de algo dejo la funcion de Javascript

```
function aumentarUno(form)
{
    if(form.numero.value < 10){
        form.numero.value ++;
    }else{
        alert("La cantidad maxima de productos a comprar es 10");
    }
}
```

Comment: Si vas a copiar y pegar 10 veces, porque no cambias el name de las formas a `formCantidad1`, `formCantidad2`... y le pasas ese valor a la funcion?

Comment: Tenes razon, medio tonta mi pregunta, gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En realidad es poco eficiente llamar a `aumentarUno` y `disminuirUno` pasándole el nombre del `form`. Lo que debieras hacer es pasarle la referencia del elemento que lo llamó:

```
<a onclick="aumentarUno(this)"><i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i></a>
```

La función recibe el elemento `a` y puede inferir de qué `form` se trata pidiendo el `parentNode` del elemento. Sabiendo el parentNode, procedes de la manera que ya tenías implementada.

De este modo te ahorras tener que ponerle un nombre único a cada `form` y modificar el código de cada uno de los links. Sólo copias y pegas hasta el infinito.

```js
function aumentarUno(element)
{
    var form = element.parentNode;
    if(form.numero.value < 10){
        form.numero.value ++;
    }else{
        alert("La cantidad maxima de productos a comprar es 10");
    }
}

function disminuirUno(element)
{
    var form = element.parentNode;
    if(form.numero.value > 0){
        form.numero.value--;
    }else{
        alert("Su carrito ya está en cero");
    }
}
```

```css
form {
margin-bottom: 3px;
}
form span {
display:inline-block;
width:100px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css"
          integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp"
          crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="cantidadProducto">
     <p>Cantidad</p>
     <form name="formCantidad">
           <span>Pan</span>
           <a onclick="aumentarUno(this)"><i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i></a>
           <input type="text" name="numero" class="numeroCantidadProducto" value="1" ReadOnly>
           <a onclick="disminuirUno(this)"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></a>
     </form>
     <form name="formCantidad">
           <span>Leche</span>
           <a onclick="aumentarUno(this)"><i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i></a>
           <input type="text" name="numero" class="numeroCantidadProducto" value="1" ReadOnly>
           <a onclick="disminuirUno(this)"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></a>
     </form>
     <form name="formCantidad">
           <span>Huevos</span>
           <a onclick="aumentarUno(this)"><i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i></a>
           <input type="text" name="numero" class="numeroCantidadProducto" value="1" ReadOnly>
           <a onclick="disminuirUno(this)"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></a>
     </form>
     <form name="formCantidad">
           <span>Harina</span>
           <a onclick="aumentarUno(this)"><i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i></a>
           <input type="text" name="numero" class="numeroCantidadProducto" value="1" ReadOnly>
           <a onclick="disminuirUno(this)"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></a>
     </form>
</div>
```

Ahora bien, es un poco impráctico tener un formulario por cada producto. Imagino que cuando quieras persistir la compra querrás enviar un objeto que represente cada producto y su respectiva cantidad. Esto se puede hacer con un poco de metaprogramación: sólo dibujas el formulario (uno solo) y declaras un arreglo de productos:

```
var productos=['pan','leche','huevos','harina'];
```

Y por cada uno de ellos, creas dinámicamente un fieldset que añades al formulario. Dentro de cada fieldset hay un input cuyo nombre es el producto. De ese modo al enviar el formulario tienes N tuplas producto-valor:

```js
var productos = ['pan', 'leche', 'huevos', 'harina'];

function aumentarUno(event) {
    var element = event.target,
        fieldset = element.parentNode,
        numero = fieldset.querySelector('.numeroCantidadProducto');
    if (numero.value < 10) {
        numero.value++;
    } else {
        alert("La cantidad maxima de productos a comprar es 10");
    }
}

function disminuirUno(event) {
    var element = event.target,
        fieldset = element.parentNode,
        numero = fieldset.querySelector('.numeroCantidadProducto');
    if (numero.value > 0) {
        numero.value--;
    } else {
        alert("Su carrito ya está en cero");
    }
}

function addFieldSet(producto) {

    var fieldset = document.createElement('fieldset'),
        span = document.createElement('span'),
        aumentar = document.createElement('a'),
        cantidad = document.createElement('input'),
        disminuir = document.createElement('a');

    span.innerText = producto;
    aumentar.onclick = aumentarUno;
    disminuir.onclick = disminuirUno;

    aumentar.className = 'fas fa-angle-up';
    disminuir.className = 'fas fa-angle-down';


    cantidad.type = "text";
    cantidad.name = producto;
    cantidad.className = 'numeroCantidadProducto';
    cantidad.value = 1;
    cantidad.readOnly = 'readonly';

    fieldset.appendChild(span);
    fieldset.appendChild(aumentar);
    fieldset.appendChild(cantidad);
    fieldset.appendChild(disminuir);

    document.getElementById('formCantidad').appendChild(fieldset);

}

function enviarCarrito() {
    document.getElementById('formCantidad').querySelectorAll('.numeroCantidadProducto').forEach(function (input) {
        console.log(input.name, input.value);
    });
}

productos.forEach(function (producto) {
    addFieldSet(producto);
});
```

```css
form {
margin-bottom: 3px;
}
form span {
display:inline-block;
width:100px;
}
.cantidad {
width:150px;
float:left;
display:inline-block;
}
fieldset {
clear:both;
 border: 0 none;
}
.numeroCantidadProducto {
margin: 0 10px;
}

.enviar {
    float: left;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css"
          integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp"
          crossorigin="anonymous">
<form name="formCantidad" id="formCantidad" class="cantidadProducto">
     <span class="cantidad">Cantidad</span>
     <input type="button" onclick="enviarCarrito()" class="enviar" value="enviar">
     
</form>
```

Comment: Uhhh, muchisimas gracias, era justo lo que necesitaba, no tengo que estar preocupandome de cambiar el nombre en cada producto, muchisimas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Si tienes la abilidad de escribir el HTML, puedes numerar las formas para distinguirlas una de otra.  Te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
function aumentarUno(form)
{
    if(form.numero.value < 10){
        form.numero.value ++;
    }else{
        alert("La cantidad maxima de productos a comprar es 10");
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="cantidadProducto">
     <p>Cantidad</p>
     <form name="formCantidad">
           <a onclick="aumentarUno(formCantidad)"><i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i>up</a>
           <input type="text" name="numero" class="numeroCantidadProducto" value="1" ReadOnly>
           <a onclick="disminuirUno(formCantidad)"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>down</a>
     </form>
</div>
<div class="cantidadProducto">
     <p>Cantidad</p>
     <form name="formCantidad1">
           <a onclick="aumentarUno(formCantidad1)"><i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i>up</a>
           <input type="text" name="numero" class="numeroCantidadProducto" value="1" ReadOnly>
           <a onclick="disminuirUno(formCantidad)"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>down</a>
     </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias, en este caso serviría, pero por ejemplo, si no se la cantidad de productos que tendré, como se haría?
Con javascript se podria hacer alguna funcion que vaya generando con diferentes name por cada producto?

Comment: Generalmente, el HTML es generado dinamicamente por el servidor, digamos en PHP.  En ese caso podrias utilizar un contador dentro de un bucle y concatenar ese valor al nombre de las formas.

Comment: Ahh oka oka, muchisimas gracias, resuelto, gracias!

Comment: De nada y bienvenido a StackOverflow en Español